# Load and pre-process NSL_KDD data set

Tags: python, machine-learning

since I am a newbie in python programming and I want to load the data according to the table of the article but I don’t know how to can do categorical training and testing the NSL_KDD dataset into(‘normal’, ‘dos’, ‘r2l’, ‘probe’, ‘u2r’).
[image]

I’ve reviewed a lot of code in GateHub to pre-process the NSL_KDD data set to categorize into five groups(‘normal’, ‘dos’, ‘r2l’, ‘probe’, ‘u2r’), but I still haven’t been able to find the code to do it right.
Can anyone help me? I really need help.

Comment: You very seldom, if ever, need pointers to containers. And your pointers doesn't point anywhere, so you can't dereference them as that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Probably remove one level of indirection. That means more or less:  remove all `*`s and replace all `**` with `*`.

Comment: `The variable 'a_n' is being used without being initialized.` This sounds pretty obvious to me. `a_n` has not been initialized. There is no `a_n = <something>` in your code. Also read the first comment.

Comment: Regarding "I don't know what size these vectors", that's the nice things about `std::vector`: They are *dynamic*. They can shrink and grov as you need. And no you don't need pointers for vectors to be dynamic, the "dynamicness" comes built-in into the vector class.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What exactly is `Autoencoder` supposed to do? How do you call it, or how do you intent to callit?

Comment: "sudo" is a Unix command. "pseudo" is a common prefix borrowed from Latin.

Comment: @arezooMoradi “Pseudo” is the established spelling since hundreds of years, as in “pseudocode”, “pseudoscience”, or “pseudoinverse”.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't determinate sizes of vectors?

The size of what vectors? You haven't shown the creation of any vector. There are only pointers to vectors, which don't initially point at anything since they are uninitialised.

The behaviour of accessing members or invoking member functions through uninitialised pointers is undefined.

Comment: @arezooMoradi what do you mean by size of a pointer? Do you mean how wide it is in bytes?

Comment: @arezooMoradi I don't see why you would need that, but you can use the `sizeof` operator to get the size of a type in bytes.

Comment: @arezooMoradi `how to can determinate the size of the pointer to the vector?` Pointer to vector is a type. You can get the size using `sizeof`. The size is the same for every single pointer to a vector.

Comment: @ eerorikaوThe main problem is that the pointer to this vector has a different size at each step. When I do not specify the size of the pointer to the vector, I get the above error, and if I want to specify the size, what size can I consider The largest size in a duplicate used or there is another solution I don't know

Comment: @arezooMoradi `has a different size at each step` It does not. The size of a type is always the same for all objects of that type. You can get the size of the pointer using `sizeof`.

Comment: @ eerorika, That's right but as shown in the code above I first define the pointer to the vector in the autoencoder that has a different size in each iteration then I use this pointer to the vector in the decoder function so I can't use the size of. Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: @arezooMoradi `sizeof` is the way to get the size of a pointer, and that size is always the same for all pointers of same type.

Comment: @ eerorika, Now I need to declare size the pointer to the vector not specified or that I can use variable size but you said the size of the vector is same but I can't use this solution. There is any solution another??

Comment: @arezooMoradi I didn't say that size of vector is the same. I said that the size of the pointer is the same. You asked for how to get the size of the pointer. The size of the vector object itself is also always the same. Different vectors may contain different number of objects however.

Comment: @ eerorika , when the definition of a vector is as follows, vector <double> a; it can have a different size in each iteration(Vector size can be enlarged)
Is this the same in the pointer to the vector (vector <double> * a;)?

Comment: @arezooMoradi the size of the vector object is always the same. But different vectors can have different number of elements. A pointer does not contain any elements. But a pointer may point at a vector.

Comment: @ eerorika, thanks to your response, you said A pointer does not contain any elements. a pointer may point at a vector why I received this error that should declare the size  So is there no way I can increase the number of addresses that the pointer specifies to a vector, such as a vector that can add the number of elements?

Comment: `why I received this error` The error message explains it. You received the error because you didn't initialise the pointer. `So is there no way I can increase the number of addresses that the pointer specifies to a vector` It's unclear what you mean by "*addresses that the pointer specifies to a vector*". What address? How are they specified? What vector?

Comment: @ eerorika, when I use a pointer to a vector to specifically address the memory that the pointer to a vector starts in this place of memory.
Can a vector pointer be initialized then occupy more memory in subsequent iterations? Such as first defining a vector then increasing the number of elements so it occupies more memory

Comment: @arezooMoradi the pointer cannot occupy any more or less memory than its size. if it points to a vector, then the size of the pointed vector may indeed change.

Comment: @ eerorika, thanks to your response, could you please example how to can change the size of the pointed vector may indeed change in each iteration in a loop

Comment: @arezooMoradi you can use the member functions of the vector. For example, `push_back` increases the number of elements by one.